# CreateProcessAsUser from c++ service creates process but no console

Tags: c++, c, winapi, win32-process

I am developing C++ service which uses CreateProcessAsUser function.
I have tested this on Windows 7 and it was working excellent.
But i am testing now my code for windows 10 and it doesnt want to work but process is created and visible in task manager, just no windows/console created.
I am trying now code snippet with cmd only without any parameters
I will really appreciate any kind of help

I can see this with task manager, so my process is created.
[task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRx6z.png)

```
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
   STARTUPINFO si;
   BOOL bResult = FALSE;
   DWORD dwSessionId;
   HANDLE hUserToken;
    // Log the client on to the local computer.
   dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();    
   WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId,&hUserToken);
   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
   si.cb= sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
   si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";
   ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));    
   LPVOID pEnv =NULL;    
   if(CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv,hUserToken,TRUE)){
   }
   else
      pEnv=NULL;    
   bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
      hUserToken,                     // client's access token
      L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",    // file to execute
      L"",                 // command line
      NULL,            // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
      NULL,               // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
      FALSE,              // handles are not inheritable
      CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT|HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS,     // creation flags
      pEnv,               // pointer to new environment block
      NULL,               // name of current directory
      &si,               // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
      &pi                // receives information about new process
   );    
   //Perform All the Close Handles tasks  
   DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnv);
   CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
   CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
   CloseHandle(hUserToken);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139037/discussion-on-question-by-szymon-mackowiak-createprocessasuser-from-c-service).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define LAA(se) {{se},SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED|SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT}

#define BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(tp, n) static const struct {ULONG PrivilegeCount;LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[n];} tp = {n,{
#define END_PRIVILEGES }};

ULONG adjustPrivileges()
{
    HANDLE hToken;

    ULONG err;
    if (OpenProcessToken(NtCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken))
    {
        BEGIN_PRIVILEGES(tp, 2)
            LAA(SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE),
            LAA(SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE),
        END_PRIVILEGES  

        AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, (::PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)&tp, 0, 0, 0);

        err = GetLastError();

        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    else
    {
        err = GetLastError();
    }

    return err;
}

ULONG cup()
{
    HANDLE hUserToken;

    DWORD dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    if (dwSessionId == MAXDWORD)
    {
        return ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
    }

    ULONG err = adjustPrivileges();

    if (err)
    {
        return err;
    }

    if (WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId,&hUserToken))
    {
        PVOID pEnv;

        if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv,hUserToken,TRUE))
        {
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
            STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
            si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";

            if (CreateProcessAsUser(
                hUserToken,                     // client's access token
                L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",    // file to execute
                NULL,                 // command line
                NULL,            // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                NULL,               // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                FALSE,              // handles are not inheritable
                CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT|HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS,  // creation flags
                pEnv,               // pointer to new environment block
                NULL,               // name of current directory
                &si,               // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                &pi                // receives information about new process
                ))
            {
                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            }
            else
            {
                err = GetLastError();
            }

            DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnv);

        }
        else
        {
            err = GetLastError();
        }
        CloseHandle(hUserToken);
    }
    else
    {
        err = GetLastError();
    }
    return err;
}
```

Comment: NtCurrentProcess()  
?

Comment: yes, this is macro `#define NtCurrentProcess() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -1 )`

Comment: SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE and SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE undeclarated, trying found in msdn but i found only this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx  ==>TEXT("SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege") got it but still doesnt work

Comment: SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE undeclarated still ;/

Comment: I have used LUID objects between BEGIN and END PIRVILIGES but still doesnt work...

Comment: @SzymonMackowiak `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE` this is well known constants declared in wdm.h

Comment: `#define SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_PRIVILEGE     (3L)` `#define SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_PRIVILEGE         (5L)`

Comment: adjustPriviliges return 1300 error:     1300 (0x514)
Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller.   ;/;/

Comment: above not important, WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId,&hUserToken) returns false

Comment: under which account you run in service ? localsystem have both this

Comment: @SzymonMackowiak are you in service ?

Comment: WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId,&hUserToken) returns false , i have only one account on W10

Comment: @SzymonMackowiak - you not understand - are you run as *LocalSystem* ?

Comment: WORKS!!, btw. what is LocaLSystem it is SYSTEM not user in task manager?

Comment: COULD YOU PLEASE PROPOSE ME GOOD WIN32 BOOK, PLEASE DONT SAY MSDN IS BEST BOO K:d ?

Comment: please any book will be great for me, btw. const_cast<wchar_t *>(parameters.c_str()) is good idea for command line parameter.... ;/ ?

Comment: YOU ARE BEST MAN, THAN YOU I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP !